# Are Agreements made by the State of Israel binding upon the Messianic Kingdom?

Tags: ymoth-hamoshiach, israel

It is known from God's commanding David to murder Saul's family over a breach of the  Gibeonites' treaty with Joshua that treaties with Enemy goyim are binding, even though Joshua's, Saul's, and David's countries were not exactly the same countries.  (2 Shmuel 21)

In the following scenario:

Sate of Israel makes some deal with the Palestinians, be it autonomy, statehood, or property and water rights.

Moshiach comes

1,000,000 Ephraimites come back from the dead and start marching on Nablus.

---

I see three potential answers:

Is the State's treaty binding on Moshiach's government?

Is the State's treaty binding only on those in its faction (roughly equivalent to the people who celebrate yom haatzmaut) and not haredim who intentionally distance themselves from the state and not the Ephraimites?

Is the State's treaty binding only on non-resurrected people?

Comment: Can you source your claim about "_God's commanding David to murder Saul's family over a breach of the Gibeonites' treaty with Joshua_"? (And, who's "we"?) While you're at it, maybe also source the part about "_1,000,000 Ephraimites come back from the dead and start marching on Nablus_".

Comment: The ephramites is the hypothetical scenario. The story of David killing Saul's descendants to appease the Gibeonites and stop God's plague is in II Shumel 21

Comment: Many people would argue that the State of Israel is not on par with the Kingdom of Israel, as it is not ruled over by a descendant of David, the proper monarchy. Kind of similar to the Hasmonean rule.

Comment: That forms the basis for a good answer. I would argue that Joshua's thing was also not on par because he wasn't from David. As a complicating factor, Jerobam was appointed by a prophet and Davidic decent may not be necessary condition for all laws pertaining to international relations.

Comment: Pretty lucky we'll have the Moshiach around to clarify this halacha up for us

Comment: Re: II Samuel 21 [:1-14]: God didn't command David to kill anyone "over a breach of the Gibeonites' treaty with Joshua". What He did was bring famine to the land for 3 consecutive years, over Saul's actions. It was the Gibeonites who asked to be given 7 of Saul's sons, for the Gibeonites to publicly hang them, in retribution for Saul seeking to kill them off, in breach of that treaty.

Comment: When God acts as the muscle for the Gibeonites and only relents when they are appeased, he is clearly signaling that he endorses their greivance.